# why am i get the segmentaion fault in Arm Assembly str instruction

Tags: arm

I'm starter using Arm assembly, I occur the segmentaion fault at line str. I think, Register has address memory about var3 and Store value to memory var3 using register 11.

I don't think there is any problem with my code..
Please solve my error code.

**exam.s**

```
.text
.global main
main:
adr r3, var1
ldr r0, [r3]
mov r0,r0, LSL #2
adr r3, var2
ldr r1, [r3]
and r1,r1,#15
orr r1,r0,r1
adr r11,var3
str r1,[r11],#4

mov r0,#0
mov r7,#1
swi 0
var1: .word 10
var2: .word 20
var3: .word 0
```

Comment: Please can you format you code. It is impossible to read as is.

Comment: If an answer is not comprehensive enough for you, you should probably *comment* on it. You *definitely* shouldn't post your own "answer" that is an extension of the question. You *can* edit your question to add detail to the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are in the `.text` section, which is non-writable in sane systems (for security and efficiency reasons).
Put a `.data` section declaration before the variable declarations.